# Can a statistical distribution of kets be equivalent to a superposition?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

I wondered if a statistical distribution of ket $|\Psi_i\rangle$ can be equivalent to a superposition.

I know it is not possible in a general case but I wondered if it is possible in restricted case (if we exclude the obvious case when the statistical distribution contains only one ket for example).

Example(s) would be appreciated.

Comment: I ask as a non expert, but the superposition idea provides definite distinct energy levels, as one example,  because of quantum theory, but does a statistical distribution allow for that?

Comment: I do not think that this is likely and I think appealing to the answer to your other question along these lines (that $\rho$ is projective iff $\operatorname{tr}\rho^2 = \operatorname{tr}\rho = 1$) is probably the way to go. A good way to see why this is unlikely is that if any non-trivial quantum superpositions look this way then they must not have a Bell inequality violation associated with them.

Answer (score 0):

For probability distributions of *kets*, there are annoying examples like a mixture of $|+z\rangle$ and $-|+z\rangle$ which abuse the global phase freedom. However if you pass to the projective Hilbert space there are no nontrivial examples.

In finite dimensions there is a very nice proof based on convex geometry. A pure state is represented by a density operator of the form $|\psi \rangle \langle \psi |$; that is, a projection onto a particular state. We can identify these points in $\text{End}(\mathcal H)$ (the space of operators on $\mathcal H$) with the projective Hilbert space $\mathcal{PH}$ via the embedding $|\psi\rangle \mapsto |\psi \rangle \langle \psi |$.

A general probability distribution is described by a density operator which is a convex linear combination of these. The space of all such operators is $\text{conv} \mathcal {PH}$, the convex hull of $\mathcal{PH}$. Since $\mathcal{PH}$ is a closed, bounded subset of $\text{End}{\mathcal H}$, the [Krein-Milman theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krein%E2%80%93Milman_theorem) (we only need Minkowski's original version) tells us that any extreme point of $\text{conv} \mathcal {PH}$ lies in $\mathcal{PH}$. And since $\text{conv} \mathcal {PH}$ is nonempty it has at least one extreme point. However $\text{End}{\mathcal H}$ is a representation of $U(\mathcal H)$ (the unitary group on $\mathcal H$) with the conjugation action. This action is transitive on $\mathcal {PH}$ and $\text{conv} \mathcal {PH}$ is an invariant subspace. Since invertible linear transformations preserve extreme points, every point in $\mathcal {PH}$ is an extreme point, and hence no pure state can be written as a statistical distribution of other pure states.

A more computational proof can be given along the lines of CR Drost's comment, showing that $\text{tr} \rho^2 \lneq \text{tr} \rho = 1$. The essential fact for this proof is that the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality is only saturated when the two vectors are linearly dependent. If you are careful enough this proof also works in infinite dimensions.

With that said, if you have multiple [superselection sectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superselection) this is only true for distributions restricted to a single sector. Otherwise one can take a rather silly example of a 2-dimensional Hilbert space with no non-identity physical observables, and then any distribution between the two states is equivalent to any other.